# Find the next row within a group based on substring condition on a column - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get the next row within a group based on the substring condition.

The below code is ignoring the grouping conditions.

```
df_shifted_rows = df[df.groupby(['id'])\
                     ['url'].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains("confirmation"))\
                     .shift(1).fillna(False)]
```

If the matching value in the current group is in the last row, then the **shift** should give me null. But it is moving to the next group and giving the first value in the next group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split it into two steps

```
m = df['url'].str.contains("confirmation")
df = df[m.groupby(df['id']).shift(1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

By tweaking the existing code. Bring the **shift** inside apply

```
df_shifted_rows = df[df.groupby(['id'])\
                     ['url'].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains("confirmation")\
                     .shift(1).fillna(False))]
```